# Trying to figure out how to do a series of animations in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I don't want to give too much detail, but I am basically doing a series of animations. I'm moving a series of numbers from one side of the screen to the next, but I don't want them to move all at once. I'm trying to break up the animations via a for loop and several if loops within, but it doesn't work. I thought using the sleep() command would help, but it hasn't. How do you make animations run in a series instead of altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method on `UIView` and set a delay time to stagger the animations.  If you want to have them run one after another, you can have one animation start in the completion block of another:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
{
    //Do your first round of animations here
} completion: ^(BOOL completed)
{
    //Start the next round
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
    {
        //second round of animations
        //Nest this structure as deep as needed
    }
}];
```

You can find the documentation for all this in the `UIView` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! It's looking a lot more like what I want now